# Когда едешь куда-то, обязательно бери свой телефон(,) полностью заряженным

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятушонка?

> Когда едешь куда-то, обязательно бери свой телефон(,) полностью заряженным.

Comment: А почему не принял? Если оборот ставится в творительный, не обособляется. В вашем примере не нужна запятая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужна:

*Когда едешь куда-то, обязательно бери свой телефон полностью заряженным*.

Оборот связан по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым. В таких случаях запятая не ставится. Это можно проверить, поставив в творительный падеж, а у вас уже в творительном.

Об этом в [справочнике Розенталя, пункт 2-3](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=237).

Comment: А какое здесь сказуемое? Бери – сказуемое.

Comment: @Sharon Ну да, _бери_ — сказуемое. А почему вы кавычками/курсивом слово _бери_ не выделили?

Comment: Оборот входит а состав сказуемого? Не похоже. Он же к телефону относится.

Comment: @Sharon Не входит, а тесно связан, как вы мне когда-то говорили. Читайте «Розенталя», ссылка выше.

Comment: Я прочитала. Но для этого правила (у Розенталя) надо, чтобы входил. Или другое правило найдите.

Comment: _Телефон полностью заряженный_. _Бери полностью заряженный_. Подходит же. И в творительный падеж можно поставить. А у автора уже творительный. Не обособляем.

Comment: Бери ТЕЛЕФОН полностью заряженный.  Давайте другое правило, я не возражаю против обособления, но грамматика здесь другая.

Comment: Бери ТЕЛЕФОН полностью заряженный. Давайте другое правило, я не возражаю против вашего решения, но ГРАММАТИКА здесь другая. –

Comment: @Sharon Я подумаю, какое другое правило можно подобрать.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже подобрала. Для вас, Максим, другим ничего не надо.

Answer (score 1):

*Бери свой телефон **полностью заряженным**.*

Никто не слышал **про двунаправленную связь?** А мне приходилось... Нет, я **не про сказуемое**, там понятное дело – именно что двунаправленная, да и Розенталь об этом говорит. Но это **частный случай**, хотя и частотный.

**Дуплексивы** (члены предложения с двунаправленной связью) одновременно относятся  **к существительному и к глаголу.**

**Определительный оборот** в нашем случае дуплексив. А относится он **к дополнению "телефон" и к глаголу.**

Вот глагол и **управляет словами**: носи (что?) телефон (В.п.). Носи (каким?) заряженным (Т.п.). Глагол задает **падежи.** Но оборот согласуется с дополнением **в роде и числе.**